# edit included php with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Let's say I have two php files.

*index.php*

```
<?php
include ('navigation.php');
?>
```

and *navigation.php*

```
<div class="nav">
<li>
<a id="nav1" href="">Navigation1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a id="nav2" href="">Navigation2</a>
</li>
</div>
```

Navigation2 should be for admins only, so it should be hidden. In this example with javascript.

*index.php*

```
<body onload="admin();"
<?php
include ('navigation.php')
?>
</body>

<script>
function admin(){
document.getElementById('nav2').style.display = "none";
</script>
```

Why isn't this working and how do I make it work?

Comment: You should have a PHP function or a variable you can use to check if the user is an admin or not.

Comment: its too long to explain how to do things right way and your question is too subjective and not specific. But basucally u can add <? if ($user == 'admin') {?><a id="nav2" href="">Navigation2</a><? } ?>

Comment: and whats with all the downvoting in php community it feels so toxic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 1):

You should put nav2 inside php if brackets as the client could easily change the css/js. Only displaying the nav2 if user is admin means non-admin users cannot access the information at all.

```
<div class="nav">
   <li>
    <a id="nav1" href="">Navigation1</a> 
   </li>
  <?php if($admin){ ?>
   <li>
    <a id="nav2" href="">Navigation2</a>
   </li>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you trying to use admin login verification in javascript you can easily do it in php. for example every admin that logs into your system definitely user a user name and password so you can just set your code to store let's say admin name and name it $_SESSION['admin']in sessions and include a session in every admin page that says `if(!$_SESSION['admin_name'] )
{

```
header("Location: admin_login.php");//redirect to login page to secure the welcome page without login access.
```

}
`
by this way if admin is not logged in and tries to access this page he will redirected to log in page.